# Create data.frames out of an initial dataframe using `lapply` in R

Tags: r, function, loops, dataframe, lapply

I was wondering how if I could make *7* other data.frames out of `dat1` using `lapply` such that at each round from left to right each pair of `1`s in `C1` and `C2` become `0` except the last two elements of `C1` and `C2`? (*see desired output below*)

```
dat1 <- data.frame(C1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
                   C2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))

dat2 <- data.frame(C1 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
                   C2 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))

dat3 <- data.frame(C1 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
                   C2 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))

dat4 <- data.frame(C1 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
                   C2 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
.
.
.
dat8 <- data.frame(C1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),  # the last desired data.frame
                   C2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `lapply` by looping over sequence of numbers (`1:7`), create a two column `matrix` with the corresponding `rep`licate of rows and `rbind` with the subset of original data with the same number of rows removed the top

```
lst1 <- lapply(1:7, function(i) rbind(matrix(rep(c(0, 0), i), ncol = 2,
      dimnames = list(NULL, c("C1", "C2"))), dat1[-seq_len(i), ]))
names(lst1) <- paste0("dat", seq_along(lst1) + 1)
```

---

It can be made shorter by using `cbind`

```
lapply(1:7, function(i) {n <- rep(0, i)
       rbind(cbind(C1 = n, C2 = n),  dat1[-seq_len(i), ])})
```

Or it can be also (inspired from @Markus comments)

```
lapply(0:8, function(i) dat1 * rep(c(0, 1), c(i, nrow(dat1)-i)))
```

If it needs to be separate objects, use `list2env` (not recommended though)

```
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Good catch @rnorouzian. Try `lapply(0:8, function(x) {dat1[0:x, ] <- 0; dat1 })`